# Как установить толщину рисуемой линии?

Tags: java, android

Рисую так:

```
cnvs.drawLine(0, 0, 300, 300, point);
```

Как выставить ширину рисуемой линии например 3 пикселя?

Comment: point.setStrokeWidth(3);
cnvs.drawLine(0, 0, 300, 300, point);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно через Paint класс установить. Вот так `youpaint.setStrokeWidth(число)`